# Is it possible to use aquarium salt instead of marine salt to raise brine shrimp to adulthood?

Tags: fish, aquarium, saltwater, growing, brineshrimp

In order to raise brine shrimp to adulthood, I have heard that it is better to use marine salt instead of aquarium salt in the grow-out tank.

Aquarium salt (sodium chloride or NaCl) is widely used to hatch the shrimp and I have had nearly a dozen successful hatches with it.

Will aquarium salt also work to raise the shrimp to adulthood in the grow-out tank?